# vimscript: How do I save and restore a register?

Tags: vim

How do I save the current state of a register and then restore it later on?

I want to ensure that my function has no unintended side-effects.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

To do this safely, you need to restore not only the contents of a register, but also its type:

```
let old_reg = getreg("a")               " Save the current content of register 'a'
let old_reg_type = getregtype("a")      " Save the type of the register as well

" <Use the register 'a' as a temporary scratch pad here>

call setreg("a", old_reg, old_reg_type) " Restore register 'a'
```

Comment: Don't forget to call `setreg` from a `:finally` zone in your function in case you call operations that may fail -- which happens often.

Comment: Thanks. The best example I could find of this was the last bit of code at: http://vimhelp.appspot.com/usr_41.txt.html#41.9
Let me know if you find something better!

Comment: Well, I can't really say "something better", but just in case, in [lh-vim-lib](https://github.com/LucHermitte/lh-vim-lib), I've defined a [`lh#on#exit()`](https://github.com/LucHermitte/lh-vim-lib/blob/74e378709c558c1a5b54f1e8d811dcd386f3109a/doc/lh-vim-lib.txt#L283) function meant to clean and restore stuff semi-automatically. However, it doesn't use `getregtype()`, yet as I wasn't aware of its (recent?) existence.

Comment: Very smooth. Counts as "something better" in my books to have one line to save and restore the state :)

Comment: Just to restore one register, it's not that pertinent. However, it becomes useful to restore several things like variables, options (that could be specialized for buffers), mappings, and so on.